How to push log in the elastic search from logstash so that we can apply aggerations on the key value pairs
I have ELK container in my local and want to push logs in key value pair via logstash because In my I need log's Keys-Values in _source key so that I can apply aggerations on it, I have already configured logstash file which creates proper format of search API response in elastic search but still it is giving wrong format of response in search query. When we apply
{"DateTime": "2024-04-19T17:47:28Z", "RequestID":"\<any_number\>","VideoRelativeTime": "0:01:08", "ImagePath": "None","VideoPath": "None", "\<key\>":\<any_number\>, "Site": "\<any_number\>", "CameraID": \<any_number\>, "Camera": "\<any_string\>", "\<key\>": \<any_number\>, "Area": \<any_string\>, "NotificationType": \<any_number\>, "Notification": "string", "RuleName": "People Counting", "RuleId": 7, "Label": "104_31_1713529048095", "isViolation": 0, "OverAllCount": "Person", "Event": "No Event", "AgeGroup": "\<any_range\>", "Gender": "\<any_string\>", "Direction": "IN", "EffectiveCount": 1, "TimeSlot": "Snacks (16-18)","color":'red',"Bags":"Backpacks","Hats":1,"UpperWear":"any_string","\<any_string\>":"Long"}

I have this log and want to apply aggeration's on it
